# I want to print only second row of my csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to print only second row of my csv file.I have two rows but i want to fetch only second row.Please help me.

Comment: `readline` the first line into the nowhere, then split the second.

Comment: iterate and if you find that row just print it. What's the difficulty and what have you tried so far?

Comment: can you provide with code

Comment: Google is your friend @kuchbhinhii.

Answer (score 1):

use code below to print only second row of CSV file named f.csv, and datas are separated by comma in each row:

```
import csv
with open('f.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 1:
            print(row)
            break
        line_count += 1
```